# Database design of Ledger Account and Balance sheet generation

Tags: database-design

I am building an application which has deposit and loan accounts management,  for which i have to develop ledger accounts and then generate balance sheet. Being new to database design, i am having a hard time in designing the database model best suited. Is there any standard model for the database design of accounts(especially ledger) which can used?

Comment: AFAIK ledgers are quite special in a few ways (storing decimal values comes to mind first).  Are you sure you want to develop an _n+1_st ledger having all the other _n_s around?  Since this is a rather sensitive field (an error could cost someone much money), with no DB design experience I would not dive into this.  Maybe you'd better hire someone with sufficient experience?

Answer (score 2):

As to what dezso said, ledgers are quite special depending on the business that is using them. You can try looking at other opensource applications with the same features and functions as your program if you're looking for a basis for your database.

You can look for some opensource projects at [Ohloh.net](http://www.ohloh.net/p?ref=homepage&q=ledger) and [Github.com](https://github.com/)

But as a fellow application developer, I would suggest you take the time to read up on some basic database design best practices and principles. And a bit of normalization, at least up to the Third Normal Form. Having a faulty database can give you a lot of headaches in the long run when maintaining your application. Refactoring database changes aren't that easy with a mature program.